# Adding values from a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a loop that scrapes website data (Deal ID and destinations) using Chromedriver and adds them to a list. I want to pair the Deal ID with the values taken from the destination table and add them to a dictionary. Each website scrape iteration has a different number of destinations (sometimes up to 20), but only one Deal ID.

I want my dictionary to have an output similar to:

```
dicts = {'Deal ID #123': ['Lisbon, Portugal', Seville, Spain'], 'Deal ID #456' : ['Monte Carlo, Monaco', 'Marseille, France', 'Istanbul, 
Turkey', 'Myrina (Limnos), Greece']}
```

Here is code so far:

```
dicts = {}
fast_deal_list = []
table_data = []


for link in urllistsmall:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(link)
    driver.find_element_by_name("LogEmail").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#MemberForm .btn").click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
   
    for fast_deal_x in soup.find('h1'):
        fast_ids = fast_deal_x.get_text()
        fast_deal_list.append(fast_ids)
    
        for table_x in soup.find_all(target="_blank"):
            table_data_run = table_x.get_text()
            table_data.append(table_data_run)
```

Comment: don't use `fast_deal_list` and `table_data` but diretly create `dicts[fast_ids] = []` and append to `dicts[fast_ids]`

Comment: better show real url so we could see real HTML.

Comment: Here is an example of one of the sites I am scraping:

https://www.vacationstogo.com/fastdeal.cfm?deal=27669&sp=y

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
dicts['Deal ID #123'] = ['Lisbon, Portugal', Seville, Spain']
dicts['Deal ID #456'] = ['Monte Carlo, Monaco', 'Marseille, France', 'Istanbul, Turkey', 'Myrina (Limnos), Greece']
```

Comment: formatting issue